# Add textfield as option for checkbox 'other' entry

Tags: forms

I am creating a form using the Drupal 6 Form API and I have a set of checkboxes. One of the options is "Other."

Is there a way to have one of these options be a fillable field? How would I define that in the options array.

Thinking something like:

```
[] Option A
[] Option B
[] Other ___________
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to add the [Select or Other](http://drupal.org/project/select_or_other) module.

It lets you define these using the Form API, CCK, Webform and some others.

Comment: Great suggestion, but I'd rather not add another module dependency to our site. Any other known work arounds?

Comment: There's no way to "embed" a select box into a checkbox array. I wrestled with this awhile back and the closest I could come up with was to add a new select box element, and just float it with CSS to make it appear inline. In the end I went with the select or other module though.

Answer (score 0):

There is a neat CCK field here: [CCK Select Other](http://drupal.org/project/cck_select_other)

I just installed it and it seems to be working fine, but don`t take my word for it as I see it is still dev. version.